# tesseract is reading passport mrz text from image incorrectly, its identifying <<<<<<<< as kkkk or cccc

Tags: scala, ocr, tesseract, image-preprocessing

I am trying to read the passport mrz string from the image i am using Tesseract and OpenCV for image processing i have tried three different ways  none of them worked

**Attempt 1**
I have this image [image: orignal mrz image] when i do ocr on it teseract read as

```
IDAUT10000999<6<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
7109094F1112315AUT<<<<<<xcc<<6
MUSTERFRAU<<ISOLDE<<<<<<<<cc<<
```

which is incorrect it treats <<< as x or c or k when I use the `mrz-java` library to read the details from the string it gives the following error

```
[error] Error parsing MRZ string: Failed to parse MRZ MRTD_TD1 IDAUT10000999<6<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
[error] 7109094F1112315AUT<<<<<<xcc<<6
[error] MUSTERFRAU<<ISOLDE<<<<<<<<cc<<
[error]  at 24-25,1: Invalid character in MRZ record: x
```

**Attempt 2**

then I converted the image to grayscale and binarized it using `OpenCV` Here is the below code

```
    val roiImagePath = "src/main/resources/ocr/passport/two-page-passport-mrz-detected.jpeg"
    
    val grayScaleROI = new Mat()
      val roiImage = Imgcodecs.imread(roiImagePath)
      Imgproc.cvtColor(roiImage, grayScaleROI, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      val roiGaryImagePath = "src/main/resources/ocr/passport/two-page-passport-mrz-detected-gray.jpeg"
    
      Imgcodecs.imwrite(roiGaryImagePath, grayScaleROI)
      val binary = new Mat()
      Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(grayScaleROI, binary, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY , 15, 25)
      val roiBinaryImagePath = "src/main/resources/ocr/passport/two-page-passport-mrz-detected-binary.jpeg"
      Imgcodecs.imwrite(roiBinaryImagePath, binary)

 val tesseract = new Tesseract()
  tesseract.setDatapath("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata")
  tesseract.setVariable("user_defined_dpi", "600")
  val result = tesseract.doOCR(new File(roiBinaryImagePath))
  val mrzStr = result.replace(" ", "")
  println(s"two page passport mrz string is: "+mrzStr)
```

it created the following binary image [image]

and the code output is
tesseract reads mrz string from the binary image as

```
IDAUT1DODD999<E<KK<KKKKEKEKEK
7AD9D9GF1TEZSISAUTKKKKKKKKKEKG
MUSTERFRAUSKISOLDEKKKKKKKKKKK
```

and `mrz-java` reads the string and generates the following error

```
[error] Error parsing MRZ string: Failed to parse MRZ null IDAUT1DODD999<E<KK<KKKKEKEKEK
[error] 7AD9D9GF1TEZSISAUTKKKKKKKKKEKG
[error] MUSTERFRAUSKISOLDEKKKKKKKKKKK
[error]  at 0-0,0: Different row lengths: 0: 29 and 1: 30
```

**Attempt 3**

then I resized the image

```
Val width = 1000 // Increase width proportionately (adjust based on your needs)
  val height = (width * binary.rows()) / binary.cols() // Maintain aspect ratio

  val resizedRoiImage = new Mat()
  Imgproc.resize(binary, resizedRoiImage, new Size(width, height), 0.0, 0.0, Imgproc.INTER_NEAREST)

  val resizedImageROIPath =  "src/main/resources/ocr/passport/two-page-passport-mrz-detected-binary-resized_image.jpg"
  Imgcodecs.imwrite(resizedImageROIPath, resizedRoiImage)
```

[image: resized image]
mrz string read by Tesseract

```
TOAUTIOOOOIISKhcceccccddddddce
FIOPOSAFIFESSISAUTReececeececs
MUSTERFRAUCCKISOLDECKccccdcddd
```

and the error is

```
[info] 15:54:04.200 633 [main] MrzParser INFO - Check digit verification failed for document number: expected 0 but got h
[error] Error parsing MRZ string: Failed to parse MRZ MRTD_TD1 TOAUTIOOOOIISKhcceccccddddddce
[error] FIOPOSAFIFESSISAUTReececeececs
[error] MUSTERFRAUCCKISOLDECKccccdcddd
[error]  at 15-16,0: Invalid character in MRZ record: c
```

can anyone please help how I read the text properly also I have tried one regex to convert c or k back to <<< it did not work either if anyone can suggest some workaround or any improvement in code please help me with that thanks

Comment: As of today... OCR is not 100% accurate. There is almost nothing which will give you "correct" results for the whole sample set. Even the best perfroming deep learning based pre-trained model will not be 100% correct. If this is a really important use-case then you should consider training one of the available ocr models for your images.

Comment: I don't think I'd trust that `mrz-java` library. In your first example Tesseract has correctly read all the data, except for some errors in the filler areas. I'd expect any worthwhile MRZ library to be able to parse the data from that correctly.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular can you recommend some good mrz-library which is based on jvm ? so that i can it in scala

Comment: I would suggest retraining tesseract on text written in OCR-B fonts. You can find an article [here](https://pretius.com/blog/ocr-tesseract-training-data/) how to do this. There are also already many repositories with [training data and training code](https://github.com/Shreeshrii/tessdata_ocrb?tab=readme-ov-file).

Comment: ... with data augmentation adding the type of noise and subsampling and thresholding that happen in the real imaging process